# How can I calculate Difference from two times in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: this is the way I am entering time]

[image: and I need difference of two times]

this is the way I am entering time and I need difference of two times

Comment: let diff = time1 - time2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `timeIntervalSince(_ anotherDate: Date)` function to get difference between two dates.

```
func findDateDiff(time1Str: String, time2Str: String) -> String {
    let timeformatter = DateFormatter()
    timeformatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"

    guard let time1 = timeformatter.date(from: time1Str),
        let time2 = timeformatter.date(from: time2Str) else { return "" }

    //You can directly use from here if you have two dates

    let interval = time2.timeIntervalSince(time1)
    let hour = interval / 3600;
    let minute = interval.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3600) / 60
    let intervalInt = Int(interval)
    return "\(intervalInt < 0 ? "-" : "+") \(Int(hour)) Hours \(Int(minute)) Minutes"
}
```

Call the function with two times to find the difference.

```
let dateDiff = findDateDiff(time1Str: "09:54 AM", time2Str: "12:59 PM")
print(dateDiff)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have 2 `Date` objects, you can get the `TimeInterval` (aka `Double`) difference using:

```
let difference = date1.timeIntervalSince(date2)
```

If you want to display the difference between the dates you should use `DateComponentsFormatter`, either like this:

```
let differenceDescription = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: difference)
```

Or you can skip getting the time interval directly and just call:

```
let differenceDescription = dateComponentsFormatter.string(from: date1, to: date2)
```

As with all formatters, don't create them every time you need to use them. They're *very* heavy objects to create and should be stored for re-use.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the two steps you can follow to solve this -

**No.1**

The recommended way to do any date math is Calendar and DateComponents

```
let difference = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: time1, to: time2)
let formattedString = String(format: "%02ld%02ld", difference.hour!, difference.minute!)
print(formattedString)
```

The format %02ld adds the padding zero

**No.2**

TimeInterval measures seconds, not milliseconds:

```
let date1 = Date()
let date2 = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 12600) // 3:30
let diff = Int(date2.timeIntervalSince1970 - date1.timeIntervalSince1970)
let hours = diff / 3600
let minutes = (diff - hours * 3600) / 60
```